# How to access a file from IIS web service hosted by ServiceHost

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, wcf, iis

In my IIS application I open a file located in the wwwroot directory that way:

```
File.ReadAllText("ConfigFile.json");
```

IISExpress tries to open the file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\ConfigFile.json`

I thought the wwwroot directory was the working directory but apparently it's not the case.

Log4net log files are written relatively to the working directory, and configuration manager files also. So I don't understand why opening a file with System.IO.File I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express` as the working directory.

What's the best solution for that problem ? I suppose I don't have to touch the Current defined working directory.

Comment: Just use `Server.MapPath` > `File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("ConfigFile.json"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution that works in a IIS WCF Service, hosted by a ServiceHost class is:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/ConfigFile.json"
```

It gives the full absolute path that is valid in my IIS Express environment and in the deployed IIS environment.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to inject `IHostingEnvironment` into your class to have access to the `ApplicationBasePath` property value

Suppose `IHostingEnvironment` type is `env` then you can use

```
File.ReadAllText(env.WebRootPath + "/ConfigFile.json");
```

like you have a function named `Read` then you can use

```
public void Read(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   File.ReadAllText(env.WebRootPath + "/ConfigFile.json");
}
```

Comment: I read IHostingEnvironment can be injected in asp.net controllers, but I have no asp.net controller, just WCF web services. How do I get the IHostingEnvironment instance ?